# How to draw a cross in Flutter canvas?

Tags: canvas, flutter

I am new to Flutter - Canvas. I need to draw a cross, just like below. I thought of drawing 2 lines and placing them in a stack with on line rotated by 90 degrees but I am not sure about it. Can anyone help me with this?

[image: this]

Comment: `void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
      final paint = Paint();
      paint.color = Colors.red;
      canvas.drawLine(new Offset(0, 0), new Offset(size.width, size.height), paint);
      canvas.drawLine(new Offset(size.width, 0), new Offset(0, size.height), paint);
}`

can you try this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) { 
    final paint = Paint(); 
    paint.color = Colors.red; 
    canvas.drawLine(new Offset(0, 0), new Offset(size.width, size.height), paint);
    canvas.drawLine(new Offset(size.width, 0), new Offset(0, size.height), paint); 
}
```

Comment: @user9469335 can you confirm the answer ?

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The above solution will provide you with 2 lines of 1-pixel width. If anyone wondering how to increase the width of the lines then the below code will help you

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const SamplePage(),
    );
  }
}

const kCanvasSize = 300.0;

class SamplePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SamplePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SamplePageState createState() => _SamplePageState();
}

class _SamplePageState extends State<SamplePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.greenAccent, width: 2)),
          width: kCanvasSize,
          height: kCanvasSize,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: CrossDrawPaint(),
            child: Container(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CrossDrawPaint extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint crossBrush = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 12;
    canvas.drawLine(const Offset(50, 50),
        Offset(size.width - 50, size.height - 50), crossBrush);
    canvas.drawLine(
        Offset(size.width - 50, 50), Offset(50, size.height - 50), crossBrush);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Hope this simple app helps the future user